# PHP PDO MySQL scrollable cursor doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, scrollableresults

For instance, I have a table with two fields: id, value. I've inserted almost 100k rows in this table.

I want to use scrollable cursor. I wrote the following code:

```
<?php
...
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM cursor_test;';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS, 3);
var_dump($row['id']); // 1, expected value is 3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Seems that mysql does not support scrollable cursors.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34625

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#105277

[Will PDO laststatment->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, $column) rerun the query each call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282310/will-pdo-laststatment-fetchallpdofetch-column-column-rerun-the-query-each)

Comment: Perhaps, but this bug was reported in 2005. How about MySQLi extension? I saw there functions to set seek... Do you know anything about it?

Comment: I used to use mysql extension (not mysqli) and it also had seek functions. Honestly I don't know how it works but I'm haven't found anything on the net that provides a similar function in PDO but just workarounds like fetching all results.

Comment: @egemadra The `data_seek()` function of mysql fetches all rows. It looks like a cursor, but it ain't.