# Reset cursor position in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$data=$stmt->fetchAll(); //Dumping the data shows the result. It is also setting the cursor at the end

while($data=$stmt->fetch())
{
//Does not enters loop
//If fetchAll() removes it work as usual
}
```

I know It dont need to fetch data twice. But my main question is How to reset cursor position in PDO?

Comment: if you don't need to fetch data twice, why do you want to reset cursor position then?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Surely you missed my point. I wanted to know how to reset the cursor in PDO. that Downvote was not justified at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK there is no possibility to reset cursor position with PDO - that might something to do with compatibility with some databases, that don't support resetting internal cursors.

If you want to iterate twice over the results, fetch it to the array and iterate over this array:

```
<?php 
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();  
foreach($results as $row) {
    // first
}

foreach($results as $row) {
    // second
}
```

**Edit** Some databases support scrollable cursors. To use that, add `PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL` flag to `prepare` method (see examples at [PDOFetch documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)). But that only adds possibility to move forward or backward, not rewind completely. Also, not all databases support that type of cursor (e.g. MySQL doesn't).

Comment: is there anything like http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-seek.php to use with PDO?

Comment: You can use additional arguments to ``PDOStatement::fetch`` method with ``PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS`` flag as linked above, but this won't work with MySQL as described here https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34625

Comment: @fallenAngel Mysql does not support cursors. So even PDO supports them if available, you can't use them with Mysql. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044636/php-pdo-mysql-scrollable-cursor-doesnt-work

Comment: @djot: Late comment, but _MySQL does not support cursors_ was as wrong a statement when you commented, as it is today: [mysql does support cursors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html)