# PHP Loop through an array second time (foreach)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, foreach

I have a foreach to loop through the data provided by a PDO SQL query:

```
foreach ($team as $row){
    $count++;
    $teamNumber = 'team'.$count;
    if ($currentScores[0]['team'.$count] == ""){
        $red = "red";
    }
    echo "<strong><font color='".$red."'>".$row['name']."</font></strong>";
    echo $currentScores[0]['team'.$count];
    if ($count < 2) 
        echo " vs ";
}
```

Now, I want to loop again through the $team array but it just returns the last value of the array during the second loop.

I tried the same thing:

```
foreach ($team as $row) {
.....
.......
}
```

How could I run again through the array?

Comment: Where's your second loop?

Comment: @Patrick Q - It's the exact same thing: foreach ($team as $row)

Comment: Please supply a few rows of your db result set, and your expected output in HTML. It will save use asking numerous questions to try and decode what you really want. Also the font tag is deprecated...

Comment: You could try reset($team).  I honestly have no idea if this would work, but it might :)

Comment: I imagine it has something to do with the cursor type of your recordset.  How do you create the $team variable?

Comment: Did you reset your $count variable?

Comment: Similar question has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111681/reset-cursor-position-in-pdo

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough, just do a foreach loop on $row as you have previously.

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    foreach($val as $a => $b) {
        echo $b;
    }
}
```